# Reference request: Yule process

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request

I am a bit at a loss when it comes to the mathematical framework of Yule processes. Exhausting Google I have found several terms that seem to be used interchangably, namely: Yule process, Yule-Furry process, Preferential Attachment process, Delayed Poisson Point Process, Pure birth process.

Out of the above names I have already studied Poisson point processes, both homogeneous and inhomogeneous and general counting processes. I am looking for a mathematical reference that rigorously introduces the Yule process and possibly discusses some of its properties (see excerpt below).

My first encounter with the Yule process comes from the following excerpt:

> **Excerpt** (doi:10.1007/s10955-018-2062-5): We will require some results about Yule processes and Yule processes with mutation. Let $Y=(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb{R}_+}$ denote the Yule process started from $Y_0=1$, such that for $t \in \mathbb{R}_+$, $Y_t$ describes the number of individuals alive at time $t$, when each individual lives forever and gives birth to children at rate $1$. The following lemma is well-known:
>
> **Lemma:** The process $e^{-t}Y_t$ is a martingale. Its terminal value $W$ exists a.s. and is exp(1) distributed.

---

**Summary**: I need a mathematical reference (also for my bibliography) which properly introduces the Yule-process and my final goal is to understand the excerpt above.

Comment: The only "Yule process" I am familiar with is the pure birth process with birth rate $\lambda_n=\lambda n$ (linear birth rate). Is there another type of process you are wanting to study?

Comment: @Math1000 thanks for your comment. Would you kindly provide a textbook reference for this pure birth process? (meanwhile, I will look for one on my own). The papers I have read so far unanimously use the terminology Yule process (and unfortunately don't provide any literature on the topic), but as mentioned in my intro I have stumbled across the terminology pure birth process myself already.

Comment: From Resnick's *Adventures in Stochastic Processes* https://i.imgur.com/cTNT8VE.png

Answer (score 1):

'Branching Processes' by Athreya & Ney contains a few pages on the the Yule process (in section 11. of chapter III), including mentioning the convergence of $e^{-t}Y_t$ to $Exp(1)$ distribution (although it is left as an exercise - the tools are given on p109 to prove it via moment generating functions).

The Yule process is also mentioned in Ross's 'Introduction to Probability Models' with some properties given.

Admittedly I am finding the same problem of relatively sparse mentions in the literature. Hope this helps.